# How to specify the folder in which the applications should get installed on Mac?

Tags: macos, directory, installation

I find that when I install applications(.dmg files), they all are installed into the folder /Volumes.And some days ago, they were installed into the folder /Applications. I don't know my macbook had suffered what kind of attacks, improper use or something like these. Anyway, it changed. I don't know how to resolve it. Is there anyone who ever had that kind of problem like me?Anyone who know how to make my macbook back to install applications into /Applications folder by default?Or anyone who know how to specific the installing folder if the default installing folder is not I want?

Answer (score 2):

You need to begin by understanding the difference between installing and application and running it from a disk image. The whole disk image situation is understandably confusing for users, but considering that this is a programming Q&A, here are the important points.

Macintosh applications are stored in special directories with the extension `.app`.  Because of the extension, these files are known by the Finder and treated as special Bundles, which are shown to the user as a single icon which cannot easily be opened further (there are other types of bundles as well, but the `.app` bundles deal specifically with applications.

Because Macintosh applications are actually directories full of files and other directories, they cannot be downloaded as a single file through the Internet without some kind of packaging.   Recently there has been a move to package these in standard `zip` files, because they are understood well by many platforms.   For many years prior to this, though, Macintosh applications were distributed on mountable Disk Images (`.dmg` format files), which themselves were multi-file containers which could support a variety of files and directories.

The key problem in both cases is that applications, once downloaded, don't necessarily move themselves to the most obvious location (the `Applications` folder on the boot volume, where Apple-installed applications are stored).   Zip files usually automatically decompress, but are left inside of your `Downloads` directory, and Disk Images are usually downloaded to the `Downloads` directory and then mounted on the desktop, showing up as a new volume under `/Volumes` and appearing in the Finder as a disk.

In most cases, applications can be run from any of these locations, leading to the particularly confusing situation of:

1. Download a disk image
2. Disk image file goes to the `Downloads folder`
3. OS X mounts the disk image
4. User runs the application just fine from the disk image
5. User reboots the Mac
6. Application appears to have disappeared

In this case, the application isn't gone, but the disk image was uncounted by the reboot, and so it isn't obvious to most users where the application has gone.

The most straightforward solution for users is to copy the applications to their `Applications` folder in order to make sure it is easy to find.

Obscure note:  This works well for Disk Images (which can subsequently be deleted), but may cause some confusion for Applications decompressed from zip files if the Application was downloaded on a disk other than the boot volume.   I this case, copying the Application may lead to having two copies of it, one in the downloaded location and one in the `Applications` folder.   This can be very confusing if you delete the application as the Finder will still locate it in the Downloads folder.   It can also be confusing when you download an update for the application manually, as it may result in multiple copies of the application in your Downloads folder.   These will usually be named "My app", "My app 1", "My app 2", etc.

Comment: Thank you very much!!You are very kind, and your answer is very easy to understand! I will check my macbook later as you say. Thanks!